# Select VPC created from cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet, amazon-eks

I am creating two EKS templates and one VPC template. In VPC template I have created 3 private and 3 public subnets which is working fine. So, I want one EKS should be in public and one EKS should be in private subnets. So how can do it via cloudformation.

```
Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

This gives me list of subnets which is 6.

```
Ec2SubnetId: 
     !Select [0, !Ref SubnetIds]
```

This selects 1st subnet from all subnets.
But I am not sure how to select 3 particular public or private subnet only in cloudformation.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you want a list of private & public subnets your VPC stack created. You can export your public & private subnets from the VPC stack & use them in your EKS stacks.

```
Outputs:
  PublicSubnets:
    Description: Public Subnets
    Value: !Join [",", [!Ref PublicSubnet1, !Ref PublicSubnet2, !Ref PublicSubnet3]]
    Export:
      Name: PublicSubnets  
  PrivateSubnets:
    Description: Private Subnets
    Value: !Join [",", [!Ref PrivateSubnet1, !Ref PrivateSubnet2, !Ref PrivateSubnet3]]
    Export:
      Name: PrivateSubnets
```

I think you should now be able to refer them in your EKS stack as

```
Ec2SubnetId: 
 !Select [0, !ImportValue PrivateSubnets]
```

or maybe a `Split` function

```
Ec2SubnetId:
  !Select [0, !Split [",", !ImportValue PrivateSubnets]]
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you have an expression that returns the first Subnet ID, and that is:

```
!Select [0, !Ref SubnetIds]
```

If you wanted all three of the Subnets, you *could* write:

```
[!Select [0, !Ref SubnetIds], !Select [1, !Ref SubnetIds], !Select [2, !Ref SubnetIds]]
```

But that expression is the same as just writing:

```
!Ref SubnetIds
```

Because `SubnetIds` already is a `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>`.